# Finding what is writing to the Transaction Log in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transaction-log

Is there a way to see what is writing to the transaction log?

I have a log file that has grown 15 Gigs in the last 20 minutes.  Is there a way for me to track down what is causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Activity monitor will show you what is executing.

`DBCC OPENTRAN` will show the oldest open transaction.

There is also the dynamic management view [`sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174302.aspx).  For example, here's a query that shows you log file usage by process:

```
-- This query returns log file space used by all running transactions.
select
    SessionTrans.session_id as [SPID],
    enlist_count as [Active Requests],
    ActiveTrans.transaction_id as [ID],
    ActiveTrans.name as [Name],
    ActiveTrans.transaction_begin_time as [Start Time],
    case transaction_type
        when 1 then 'Read/Write'
        when 2 then 'Read-Only'
        when 3 then 'System'
        when 4 then 'Distributed'
        else 'Unknown - ' + convert(varchar(20), transaction_type)
    end as [Transaction Type],
    case transaction_state
        when 0 then 'Uninitialized'
        when 1 then 'Not Yet Started'
        when 2 then 'Active'
        when 3 then 'Ended (Read-Only)'
        when 4 then 'Committing'
        when 5 then 'Prepared'
        when 6 then 'Committed'
        when 7 then 'Rolling Back'
        when 8 then 'Rolled Back'
        else 'Unknown - ' + convert(varchar(20), transaction_state)
    end as 'State',
    case dtc_state
        when 0 then NULL
        when 1 then 'Active'
        when 2 then 'Prepared'
        when 3 then 'Committed'
        when 4 then 'Aborted'
        when 5 then 'Recovered'
        else 'Unknown - ' + convert(varchar(20), dtc_state)
    end as 'Distributed State',
    DB.Name as 'Database',
    database_transaction_begin_time as [DB Begin Time],
    case database_transaction_type
        when 1 then 'Read/Write'
        when 2 then 'Read-Only'
        when 3 then 'System'
        else 'Unknown - ' + convert(varchar(20), database_transaction_type)
    end as 'DB Type',
    case database_transaction_state
        when 1 then 'Uninitialized'
        when 3 then 'No Log Records'
        when 4 then 'Log Records'
        when 5 then 'Prepared'
        when 10 then 'Committed'
        when 11 then 'Rolled Back'
        when 12 then 'Committing'
        else 'Unknown - ' + convert(varchar(20), database_transaction_state)
    end as 'DB State',
    database_transaction_log_record_count as [Log Records],
    database_transaction_log_bytes_used / 1024 as [Log KB Used],
    database_transaction_log_bytes_reserved / 1024 as [Log KB Reserved],
    database_transaction_log_bytes_used_system / 1024 as [Log KB Used (System)],
    database_transaction_log_bytes_reserved_system / 1024 as [Log KB Reserved (System)],
    database_transaction_replicate_record_count as [Replication Records],
    command as [Command Type],
    total_elapsed_time as [Elapsed Time],
    cpu_time as [CPU Time],
    wait_type as [Wait Type],
    wait_time as [Wait Time],
    wait_resource as [Wait Resource],
    reads as [Reads],
    logical_reads as [Logical Reads],
    writes as [Writes],
    SessionTrans.open_transaction_count as [Open Transactions(SessionTrans)],
    ExecReqs.open_transaction_count as [Open Transactions(ExecReqs)],
    open_resultset_count as [Open Result Sets],
    row_count as [Rows Returned],
    nest_level as [Nest Level],
    granted_query_memory as [Query Memory],
    SUBSTRING(SQLText.text,ExecReqs.statement_start_offset/2,(CASE WHEN ExecReqs.statement_end_offset = -1 then LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), SQLText.text)) * 2 ELSE ExecReqs.statement_end_offset end - ExecReqs.statement_start_offset)/2) AS query_text
from
    sys.dm_tran_active_transactions ActiveTrans (nolock)
    inner join sys.dm_tran_database_transactions DBTrans (nolock)
        on DBTrans.transaction_id = ActiveTrans.transaction_id
    inner join sys.databases DB (nolock)
        on DB.database_id = DBTrans.database_id
    left join sys.dm_tran_session_transactions SessionTrans (nolock)
        on SessionTrans.transaction_id = ActiveTrans.transaction_id
    left join sys.dm_exec_requests ExecReqs (nolock)
        on ExecReqs.session_id = SessionTrans.session_id
        and ExecReqs.transaction_id = SessionTrans.transaction_id
    outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ExecReqs.sql_handle) AS SQLText
where SessionTrans.session_id is not null -- comment this out to see SQL Server internal processes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you transaction log has grown so much is such a short time this means that a lot of statements that make data or structure changes have been executed. If your database works with large blob records you can try looking there first.

Profiler won't help you much in finding out what happened previously but it can help you if this is still going on.

If you want to read into transaction log, you will need a 3rd party [transaction log reader](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx). The best solution on the market is [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) which saved me couple times in similar situations.

However, if your database is running on sql server 2000, you can try to use SQL Log Rescue from Red Gate cause it's free. Thrid solution is to try and find Lumigent Log Explorer (product is discountinued but maybe you can find it somewhere online).

Try'em all and see which one works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql server profiler which show every transaction executed and it's start time and end time and many things and i think you can see what causing your problem.
I hope this help you.